# How to filter for rows that have greater than a specified count of consecutive integers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that is like this:

```
Frame_Number Parts X Y

7      Y.     7. 9
7      G      :  :
8      Y      :  :
8      Y      :  :
8      Y      :  :
9      :      :  :
10
18
18
18
18
19
20
20
21
21
22
23
24
24
25
25
25
26
27
28
29
29
29
29
30
42
45
80
80
80
81
81
81
82
82
83
109
109
120
121
122
123
124
125
126
127
128
129
130
131
132
132
132
133
190
200
202
204
205
206
:
1000
```

I want to select the subset of this dataframe that has at least 25 consecutive number.

For example,
in my dataset there is [1,1,2,3,5,6,8,9,10..33,34,35,36,37,40,.65.1000]

So, here from 8 to 37, we have consecutive values and more than 25 (different)numbers. Also, from 40 to 65 we say that there are 25 consecutive numbers present. So, I want to select these sets of rows where there are at least 25 or more consecutive data frames present as a subset.

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Create groups of consecutive integers:**

You can create a series `s` that takes the cumulative count of non-consecutive integers. That means consecutive rows will have the same values in the series `s` as they are in the same "group" of consecutive integers

2. **Count consecutive integers within groups:**

Then, you can create `m` by calculating the `count` of consecutive integers in each group using `.groupby(s)`

3. **Filter for groups that have consecutive values > n:**

Filter the `df` by `m` where greater than any value you specify (25 in this case)

---

```
df = df.sort_values('A').drop_duplicates(subset='A')
s = (df['A'] != df['A'].shift(1) + 1).cumsum()
m = df.groupby(s).transform('count')['A']
df = df[m>10]
df
Out[1]: 
      A
7    18
11   19
12   20
15   21
16   22
17   23
18   24
20   25
23   26
24   27
25   28
26   29
30   30
44  120
45  121
46  122
47  123
48  124
49  125
50  126
51  127
52  128
53  129
54  130
55  131
56  132
59  133
```

Another option to keep dupliccates:

```
df = d2.copy()
s = ((df['A'] != df['A'].shift(1)) & (df['A'] != df['A'].shift(1) + 1)).cumsum()
m = df.groupby(s).transform('count')['A']
df = df[m>10]
df
Out[1]: 
      A
7    18
8    18
9    18
10   18
11   19
12   20
13   20
14   21
15   21
16   22
17   23
18   24
19   24
20   25
21   25
22   25
23   26
24   27
25   28
26   29
27   29
28   29
29   29
30   30
44  120
45  121
46  122
47  123
48  124
49  125
50  126
51  127
52  128
53  129
54  130
55  131
56  132
57  132
58  132
59  133
```

Comment: Thank you for this. In my dataset, the numbers are not in order.So, it's like [ 1,1,1,2,2,5,5,5,5,5,89,89,89,...].For this case it's not working.Could you suggest an edit ?

Comment: @amarykya-ishtmella Kindly post full sample data in question up to 40 or so or whatever number sideways as a list.

Comment: I have edited the data part in the question. So, the data I have is frames. There are multiple rows per frame (sometimes) and there are missing frames ( so the frame numbers can be like [3,4,6,9..] they are increasing but can have missing numbers in between. I want to check if consecutive numbers of frames are present  and I want to check against a threshold.Like is there at least 10 or more consecutive frames present (frame number 18 to 30 is consecutive) then from frame number (120 to 133) is another consecutive which has at least above 10 frames occurring simultaneously.

Comment: @amarykya_ishtmella see my updated answer. Make sure the values are sorted and drop duplicates. Then, proceed from there.

Comment: is there a way without dropping the duplicates as in the next step I will need to use the subset of the dataframe with the duplicate values? I will try this one now

Comment: thank you very much it works.I learned something new, thank you for helping out.I will try to work my around with this

Comment: okay, I posted another option as well at the end of my answer. Good luck!

Comment: perfect!Thank you :))